# how to make status bar use background as image in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, statusbar, react-native-cli

I want this status bar to take the background as this image, is it possible with react native and what could be the approach

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale background image to fit device dimension then change StatusBar background to `transparent` and enable `translucent`

```js
<StatusBar
   backgroundColor="transparent"
   translucent={true}
/>
```